# How to decrease the size of a pixel in a collection of images?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google, pixel

How to decrease the size of a pixel in a collection of images? I need to take the PERSIANN images and reduce the pixel to the size of the CHIRPS. One has 0.05 ° resolution and the other 0.25 °

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `.reduceResolution()`.

Working example is provided in the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/resample).